Calculate time period of circular-orbiting source based on max frequency observed from within circle-of-motion (doppler effect)
This puzzle refers to Doppler Effects observed in circular motion (at non relativistic speeds, so $v\ll c$).
Suppose there is a source emitting a frequency, $f_s$. An observer at the center will experience no shift in observed frequency ($f_r$). As they move towards the circle of motion, $f_r$ starts to shift up and down "sinusoidally". I use quotes, as it starts go skew as the observer approaches the source's orbit, because $f_r$ gradually increases as the source approaches, and then instantly drop to a minimum after it passes the observer.
My goal here is to derive an equation that, given the parameters of this environment:
$$X: Distance\ of\ observer\ from\ center\\R: Radius\ of\ orbit\ of\ source\\C:Speed \ of\ wave\ in\ medium\\f_\max\ :Maximum\ observed\ frequency\\f_s :Source\ frequency$$
I've tried my hand at deriving something, but it is almost correct. It just breaks down when X approaches R and the sinusoidal-look starts to break down and the actual Time period, $T_s$, starts to deviate from the actual value. Here's my take:
The source moves in a circle of radius $R$, with its position as a function of time:
$$\mathbf{r}_{s}(t)=(R\cos(\omega t),R\sin(\omega t)),$$
where $ω=2π/T_s$​ is the angular frequency of the source, and $T_s=1/f_s$​ is its time period.
And for the distance,
$$d(t)=\sqrt{(R\cos(\omega t)-X)^{2}+(R\sin(\omega t))^{2}}$$
$$d(t)=\sqrt{R^{2}-2R X\cos(\omega t)+X^{2}}$$
From the Doppler Effect equation,
$$f_{r}(t)=f_{s}\left(1-\frac{v_{\mathrm{rel}}(t)}{c}\right)$$
Substituting $v_{rel}$,
$$f_{r}(t)=f_{s}\left(1+\frac{R\omega X\sin(\omega t)}{c\sqrt{R^{2}-2R X\cos(\omega t)+X^{2}}}\right)$$
Since the maximum $f_r$ occurs when $sin(\omega t)=1$,
$$f_{\mathrm{max}}=f_{s}\left(1+{\frac{R\omega X}{c\sqrt{R^{2}+X^{2}-2R X\cos(\pi)}}}\right)$$
$$f_{\mathrm{max}}=f_{s}\left(1+\frac{R\omega X}{c(X+R)}\right)$$
Since $\omega = 2\pi/T_s$,
$$f_{\mathrm{max}}=f_{s}\left(1+{\frac{2\pi R X}{c T_{s}(X+R)}}\right)$$
$$T_{s}=\frac{2\pi R X}{c(X+R)\left(\frac{f_{\mathrm{max}}}{f_{s}}-1\right)}$$
This equation is almost right. I do not know where to proceed from here. Additionally, here is the equation I used to check the "actual" values of T should be:
$$d\left(t\right)=\sqrt{\left(R^{2}-2RX\cos\left(\omega t\right)+X^{2}\right)}$$
$$r_{rel}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(d\left(t\right)\right)$$
$$\boxed{f_{r}=f_{s}\left(1-\frac{r_{rel}}{c}\right)}$$
